# Strongly Regular Graph and GI-Completeness

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, graph-isomorphism, structural-complexity

It is not known if graph isomorphism (GI) for [strongly regular graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) (SRGs) is in **P**. Are there any hints that it might or might not be **GI**-Complete? Are there any strong consequences in such cases? (Similar to the *belief* that GI may not be NP-Complete).

Comment: I personally believe that the problem is strictly easier than GI, because of Spielman's algorithm for SRGs, which has a smaller exponent than the one by Luks for general graphs. There just seems like there's so much more structure! (which ultimately might mean nothing)

Comment: While I tend to agree with @TimothySun, I don't really know formal reasons to think that SRGI is strictly easier than GI. E.g., if there is a $O(n)$ reduction from GI to SRGI then that would yield a better algorithm for GI than currently known, but if the reduction blows up the number of vertices even to $O(n^{3/2})$ then it would not have that surprising consequence. As to your 2nd q., I doubt there are any complexity consequences of any problem (known to reduce to GI) being GI-complete, since it's so unrelated to most other complexity classes (unlike the fact that GI being NPC collapses PH).

Answer (score 11):

I believe all known GI-completeness results are *functorial* (definition in the paper), and Babai has recently shown (ITCS 2014, [free author's copy](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/14itcs.pdf)) - based on bounds on the structure of automorphism groups of strongly regular graphs - that there is no functorial reduction from GI to strongly regular GI.