# Graph Isomorphism of Strongly Regular Graph with fixed parameter

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, graph-isomorphism

$G, H$ are strongly regular graphs with parameter $(n, r, \lambda, \mu)$ where $\lambda$ is constant.

Here,
$n$  is the number of total vertices. Each graph is $r$ regular. Every two adjacent vertices of $G$ and $H$ have $\lambda$ common neighbours. Every two non-adjacent vertices of $G$ and $H$ have $\mu$ common neighbours.

What is the computational complexity of *Graph Isomorphism Algorithm of Strongly Regular Graph*  where $\lambda$ is constant?

Comment: Related : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12715/strongly-regular-graph-and-gi-completeness